# Ajax Sync True Not Working And Loading Too Slow

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using ajax to append my data to a frontend table from MySQL database where my entire system is running on CodeIgniter.

I have added async true but the problem is still the same. I am not sure where and what I am doing wrong. When I enter this URL "somelist" on the browser the data loads up very fast.

```
$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      async: true,
      cache: true,
      url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>somelist",
      dataType: "JSON",
      beforeSend: function(){
         swal({
            title: "Loading...",
            text: "Getting Data!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: false,
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: false,
            showConfirmButton: false,
          });
      },
      success: function(data){
        swal.close();
        swal({
            title: "Successful!",
            text: "Data Loaded!",
            type: "success",
            showCancelButton: false,
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: false,
            showConfirmButton: false,
          });
        swal.close();
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
        partno = JSON.parse(value.Part_No);
        if(partno != null) {
          partno1 = partno.join('<br>');
        } else {
          partno1 = '';
        }
        wf = JSON.parse(value.WF);
        if(wf != null) {
          wf1 = wf.join('<br>');
        } else {
          wf1 = '';
        }
        $('.storelist').append(`<tr>
          <td ><input id='storeall' name='storeall' type='radio' style='width:50px;'></td>  
          <td class='storeid'>`+value.Store_ID+`</td>
          <td class='clientname'>`+value.Client_Name+`</td>                     
          </tr>`);
      });

          //window.location.reload();
      },
      error: function() {
        swal("Oops", "We couldn't connect to the server!", "error");
      }
  });
```

code from database

```php
function get_somestorelist()
    {
        $data = array();        
        $this->db->order_by('ID', 'DESC');
        //$Q = $this->db->get('stores','500');
        $Q = $this->db->get('stores');

        if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        $Q->free_result();
        return $data;
    }
```

No errors but loading time are too long. 
Please advise.

Comment: `async: true` is redundant, AJAX is already asynchronous.  (And trying to make it *synchronous* is a famously bad idea.)  What specifically is taking a long time?  Use your browser's debugging tools.  Is the response from the server what's taking the time?  Is a specific operation in the client-side code taking a long time?  Something else?  "Loading time is too long" isn't really something we can solve by itself.

Comment: you can make a jQuery Ajax request synchronous with `async: false`, but `true` is already the default value. However, what makes you say that your `async: true` doesn't work?